# How to keep fragments in memory on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm creating a tablet optimised application using fragments. I have a thin navigation fragment down the left hand side with buttons to controls what fragments will be loaded into the two ViewGroup containers which take up the rest of the screen.

For example, if a button in the navigation fragment is pressed, the 1st container will be loaded with an item list fragment (eg for settings, customers etc) and the second container will be loaded with fragment to show the item details.

Since I want to retain the fragments in memory (so, when navigating from Settings to Customers and then back to Settings, the previous Settings fragments should be there so the user doesn't lose where they were up to) - I have created fragments instance variables for the Activity

```
SettingsListFragment settingsListFragment;
SettingsDetailFragment settingsDetailFragment;
CustomerListFragment customerListFragment;
CustomerDetailFragment customerDetailFragment;
```

I then create these fragments when neccessary and replace the containers with the fragments as needed. eg.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
if(settingsListFragment == null){
   settingsListFragment = new SettingsListFragment();
}           

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_left, settingsListFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

My question is, how can I retain these instances accross an orientation change?

I'm assuming that I shouldn't use the activities onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() method according to
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html because "Be very careful with the object you pass through onRetainNonConfigurationChange() ...This means you should never pass a View, a Drawable, an Adapter, etc"

I've also attempted to get the Fragment from the fragment manager,
`Fragment clf = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("CLIENT LIST");`
but it comes back as null. I think it gets released after the fragment is replaced.

Thanks for any help/advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (or really shouldn't) retain fragments in that way. I'm guessing it's state you want to keep.

If you store your state in [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) you can later retrive it in [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) or [`onActivityCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29).  So after you go back (you'll have to add the `FragmentTransaction` to the back stack) you can restore the state from the Bundle to which you saved it!

`FragmentManager` will take care of handling configuration changes and restoring your fragments in their current views.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend letting android redraw your objects. 
If you want keep data on orientation change you should keep those in a service component. This way the data will not be lost on orientation change.

otherwise you could always do this:

put this in your manifest

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

put thisin your activity class

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

when using this method your activity will not be redrawn, so your layout will not be adjusted when you are using a seperate XML layout file for either landscape or portrait orientation

Answer (score 1):

One more thing, you can retrieve the stored Fragment references by `FragmentManager#putFragment` and `FragmentManager#getFragment`.