# Should I keep reference to fragments in case of NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In [training page](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)  of `NavigationDrawer`, on `selectItem` method, it creates new a `Fragment` each time it navigates. In addition its `Fragment`s are identical in code. What I have in my case is totally different `Fragment`s.

My question is, should I create my `Fragments` and keep reference of them and use that reference to replace while navigating, or is it really good practice to recreate them?

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893050/how-to-keep-fragments-in-memory-on-orientation-change) I can keep references and use them while replacing(not sure, will be tried in place tomorrow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge recreating fragments while doing navigation causes the entire life-cycle of the fragment to kick in and increases the memory consumption. It would be much better if you replace the existing fragment by using the attach/detach method and so on. You can see the various methods available on the fragmentTransaction here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Hope this helps you.

Comment: what you offered is awesome except it requires api level 13. I am currently working on api level 11+.

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem. The link i pasted clearly says available in api 11

Comment: ohh i see the problem. Try using the add/remove method in place of attach/detach for pre- API 13

Comment: ok, one last question before acceptal(it is actually included in main question as hidden), on document he uses `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();` should I use replace or remove and add in order(detach and attach on newer devices)

Comment: Yes you can do that. You will have to instantiate the fragment first for using the detach/attach, add/new if you are using it in an activity. If you are just extending a fragment on your class, then its available for overriding.